# shell script in remote machine not working with ssh

Tags: shell, ssh, sh, atg

I am trying to execute a script located in machine B from machine A.
PS - The script is trying to restart ATG instance on a JBOSS server.
I tried following commands -

```
ssh user@hostname /path/to/script/remotescript.sh arg1 arg2
ssh user@hostname "bash -c '/path/to/script/remotescript.sh arg1 arg2'"
ssh user@hostname exec /path/to/script/remotescript.sh arg1 arg2
```

The script works locally, but when executed from a remote location the script throws the following exception -

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No     ClassLoaders found for:     oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAException

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's... nice? How are we supposed to know what's in the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the mystery is resolved. This worked -

SSH -q USER@hostname "**source /export/home/jboss/.bash_profile;** /bin/bash /path/to/script/remotescript.sh arg1 arg2"

Source command with loading bash profile did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you can show the code of remotescript then it would be easier for solution.

Try using ssh -t option once.

Answer (score 0):

If you ssh to the remote machine, with

```
ssh user@hostname
```

and then run the script

```
/path/to/script/remotescript.sh arg1 arg2
```

at the resultant remote prompt, do you get the same error?

It looks like you have not provided the right Oracle JDBC drivers in JBOSS. Sort that error out first, and then see if you can run it via ssh with a single command